# AdMob RewardedAd fails to load after some time

Tags: android, admob

I've implemented a game in Android that uses RewardAds to reward the player with coins and hearts, also I've added some Interstitial and Native Ad. Everything works fine when I try to play the RewardAds for 8-10 times in the same Activity or even in other activities but after that the add fails to load. After some debugging I found out that my rewardAd variable is still **null** although *RewardedAd.load()* method is called. The only way I can make the ads load again is by restarting the app.
The Interstitial/Native Ads work perfectly every time.

Here is the code:

```
private RewardedAd livesRewardedAd;
private FullScreenContentCallback callback;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initializeRewardAd();
    }

private void initializeRewardAd() {
        callback = initializeFullScreenCallback();

        if (livesRewardedAd == null) {
            loadLivesRewardAd(callback);
        }
    }

private FullScreenContentCallback initializeFullScreenCallback() {
        return new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                livesRewardedAd = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                livesRewardedAd = null;
                loadLivesRewardAd(callback);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                Toast
                        .makeText(getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.somethingWentWrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        };
    }

private void loadLivesRewardAd(final FullScreenContentCallback callback) {
        RewardedAd.load(
                this,
                StringHelper.REWARD_AD_LIVES_ID,
                new AdRequest.Builder().build(),
                new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd ad) {
                        livesRewardedAd = ad;
                        livesRewardedAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(callback);
                    }
                });
    }

private void playLivesRewardAd() {
        if (livesRewardedAd != null) {
            livesRewardedAd.show(
                    this,
                    rewardItem -> {
                        int newLifeNo = lifeNo + 3;
                        updateUserLifeNo(newLifeNo);
                    });
        } else {
            Toast
                    .makeText(getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.somethingWentWrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

After some time only

```
Toast
                    .makeText(getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.somethingWentWrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
```

is executed when running **playLivesRewardAd()**

Comment: In the code you added it is not visible when you call the `playLivesRewardAd()`. Additionally, you have 2 cases in `callback` where you intentionally set the `livesRewardedAd = null` have you tried removing those? or track if any of these are called when the problem appears?

Comment: @madlymad The playLivesRewardAd is called when pressing a pop-up button which shows only when the user has 0 lives left. I've added some more logs and I've waited a little longer now to see if the ad fails to load and it seems it does. After some successful ad shows the `onAdFailedToLoad` is called and the error seems to be `"Code": 0,  "Message": "Internal error."` I used the test adId. Thank you for your quick reply.